# retrieving Illegal string offset id

Tags: php, string, offset

have a problem retrieving  Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\gestione_articoli_slider.php and the same for 'titolo'

I wanna have a form to upload images udating mysql row sending to upload_image3.php the id of the row i wanna update. So my goal is retrieving all title from my articles and showing them in the option value of my form. Connection is ok by data2->connetti();

Which is the problem with the offset? if a echo $row_titoli['title'] i get the correct output.

Thanks for help, here is my code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_image3.php" method="post">
    <i>Immagine:</i> 
    <input name="form_img" type="file" /><br />
    <select name="id">
        <?php 
        include "include/connection2.php";
        $data2 = new MysqlClass();
        $data2->connetti();

        $titoli = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articoli");
        $row_titoli = mysql_fetch_array($titoli);

        foreach($row_titoli as $titole){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $titole['id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $titole['titolo']; ?> </option>

        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: *"Illegal string offset"* → `$titole` is a **string**, not an array. Why? Because `mysql_fetch_array` only fetches a one-dimensional array!

Comment: so how can i solve this? sorry but i'm little newb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
$row_titoli = mysql_fetch_array($titoli);
foreach($row_titoli as $titoli){
```

you should use

`while($row_titoli = mysql_fetch_assoc($titoli)){`

**BUT**

`mysql_*` set of functions is **DEPRECATED** and you should be using the `PDO` object oriented alternative, or the `mysqli` Class.

Comment: click on the 'tick' next to this answer, below the voting arrows.